# E0597 trying to loop over an vector

Tags: loops, rust, set, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm teaching myself Rust by doing some programming exercises. Here I am have a `Vec<String>` I read out of a file, and I am trying to put the letters in each line in a `HashSet`, then taking the intersection of all the lines.

When I do this I get an error saying my loop variable does not live long enough.

I have an intuition what is wrong -- I have a variable `l` whose lifespan is one iteration of the loop, and another variable candidates whose lifespan is the entire loop, and the second variable is borrowing from the first. But how do I fix this?

```
let mut candidates = HashSet::<&u8>::new();
let mut sum = 0;
for l in lines { // lines is Vec<String>
    if candidates.len()==0 {
        candidates = HashSet::<&u8>::from_iter(l.as_bytes());
        println!("candidates = {:?}", candidates);
    } else if l.len() == 0 { // error message "borrow later used here"
        // end of group
        sum = sum + candidates.len();
        candidates = HashSet::<&u8>::new();
    } else {
        let h2 = HashSet::<&u8>::from_iter(l.as_bytes()); // error message "borrowed value does not live long enough"
        candidates = candidates.intersection(&h2).copied().collect();
        println!("candidates = {:?}", candidates);
    }
    println!("{}", l);
}
```

I tried making a copy of `l`

```
let mut l2:String = "".to_string();
for l in lines {
    if candidates.len()==0 {
        l2 = l.to_string();
        candidates = HashSet::<&u8>::from_iter(l2.as_bytes());
```

but I get a different error saying `error[E0506]: cannot assign to l2 because it is borrowed`.

Comment: can you just borrow as in `for l in &lines {`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as_bytes` converts your `l` String to a byte slice. Slices are references to a contiguous sequence of elements. The compiler points out that at the end of your for loop, the reference is invalid.

One solution would be to iter over String references with `&lines`:

```rust
    let mut candidates = HashSet::<&u8>::new();
    let mut sum = 0;
    for l in &lines { // <= HERE iter over String references which lives outside the for loop
        if candidates.len()==0 {
            candidates = HashSet::<&u8>::from_iter(l.as_bytes());
            println!("candidates = {:?}", candidates);
        } else if l.len() == 0 {
            // end of group
            sum = sum + candidates.len();
            candidates = HashSet::<&u8>::new();
        } else {
            let h2 = HashSet::<&u8>::from_iter(l.as_bytes());
            candidates = candidates.intersection(&h2).copied().collect();
            println!("candidates = {:?}", candidates);
        }
        println!("{}", l);
    }
```

A second solution would be to copy your l String.

```rust
    let mut candidates = HashSet::<u8>::new();
    let mut sum = 0;
    for l in lines { // lines is Vec<String>
        if candidates.len()==0 {
            candidates = HashSet::<u8>::from_iter(l.clone().into_bytes());
            println!("candidates = {:?}", candidates);
        } else if l.len() == 0 {
            // end of group
            sum = sum + candidates.len();
            candidates = HashSet::<u8>::new();
        } else {
            let h2 = HashSet::<u8>::from_iter(l.clone().into_bytes());
            candidates = candidates.intersection(&h2).copied().collect();
            println!("candidates = {:?}", candidates);
        }
        println!("{}", l);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`candidates` can contain references into `l` from the previous loop iteration, but `l` is dropped at the end of each loop iteration, hence the compile errors. You can avoid all this trouble by using `into_bytes` instead of `as_bytes` so you get owned values instead of references. Here's a cleaned up refactored version:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn example(lines: Vec<String>) {
    let mut candidates: HashSet<u8> = HashSet::new();
    let mut sum = 0;

    for line in lines {
        dbg!(&line);
        let h2: HashSet<u8> = line.into_bytes().into_iter().collect();
        if candidates.is_empty() {
            candidates = h2;
        } else if h2.is_empty() {
            sum += candidates.len();
            candidates = HashSet::new();
        } else {
            candidates = candidates.intersection(&h2).copied().collect();
        }
        dbg!(&candidates);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3780d03e672ba3b7a8227b6e5863368)

Comment: Another advantage of this solution is that `u8` is smaller and faster than `&u8`.